# Ember: Proper way to test tagName

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, ember-cli

Given the following component integration test:

```js
test('it has the correct tagName of aside', function(assert){
  this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);
  assert.equal(this.$().prop('tagName'), 'ASIDE');
});
```

It fails saying the `tagName` is a `div` despite me changing the `tagName` in the component:

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'aside',
  ...
});
```

Looking at the page source, it is infact an `aside`, but the intergation test doesn't see it.

A similar failure happens if I try to test for `class` attribute as well. I'm appending a class name to the `classNames` collection in the component, but all that's returned when I query it is `ember-view`.

What is the proper way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an integration test, `this.$()` refers to the entire inline rendered Handlebars template. The root element of this is always a `<div>`.

To find your component's element, you'll want something like `this.$('> .my-component')`, basing the selector on whatever your component's class name is. That should allow you to assert on the tag name property.